# Is the Nested Radical Constant rational or irrational?

Tags: calculus, limits, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Given the sequence $A_n=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{\dots+\sqrt{n}}}}}$:

- Are there any known rational elements in $A_n$, or has it been proved that all are irrational?
- Is there any proof for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ (a.k.a. [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html)) to be rational or irrational?

Comment: There is no rational $A_n$ other than $A_1$.

Comment: Related: [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists)

Comment: @MJD How can you paste links into comments with titles like that?

Comment: @gt6989b `[title](URL)` ⇒ [title](http://URL)

Answer (score 12):

The square of a rational number is always rational, so the square *root* of an irrational is also necessarily irrational.

Therefore, as you go through the sequence
$$\sqrt n, \sqrt{(n-1)+\sqrt{n}}, \sqrt{(n-2)+\sqrt{(n-1)+\sqrt{n}}}, \ldots, A_n$$
once you hit even one irrational number, $A_n$ at the far end of the sequence will be irrational too.

If $n$ is *not* a perfect square, this makes $A_n$ irrational right away.

On the other hand, if $n$ is a perfect square, $n=k^2$, then the *second* element in the computation is $\sqrt{k^2+k-1}$, which is strictly between $k$ and $k+1$ and therefore irrational (unless $k=1$).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! And what about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ itself? Has it been proved irrational?

Comment: How does that follow? `The square of a rational number is always rational, so the square root of an irrational is also necessarily irrational.` The first part seems obvious to me, the second less so...

Comment: @ArtB: If there were an irrational number a rational square root, then the square of the rational square root would be the original irrational number, which contradicts the fact that the square of a rational number is rational.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense once you spell it out like that. Thanks for that! To anyone in the future, I believe he meant to say <q>If there were an irrational number _with_ a rational square root,</q>

Answer (score 8):

For the first question: If $A_n$ is rational, we can prove that $\sqrt{n}$ is rational, thus $n$ is a perfect square, and then we can prove that $\sqrt{n-1+\sqrt{n}}$ is rational, and hence $n-1+\sqrt n$ is a perfect square. But if $n>1$, $$(\sqrt n)^2<n-1+\sqrt{n}<(\sqrt{n}+1)^2$$

Comment: Very Nice!!!!!!

Comment: And what about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ itself? Has it been proved irrational?

Comment: I answered the first question only, @barakmanos.I have no idea about the second.