# Nested Radicals which is approximately 1.75

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, nested-radicals

We know that from using Ramanujan formula, we have :
$$3 = \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$$
Now, suppose I define the following sequence :
$$ x_1 = 1\\
x_2 = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\\
\vdots\\
x_n = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}
$$
I have checked numerically the the value for $x_n$ is approximately $1.7$ but it does not equate to $\sqrt3$.

Can anyone help me to solve the exact value of this sequence?

Comment: Notice that the sequence you defined does not quite resemble the expression from Ramanujan's formula.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774193/is-the-nested-radical-constant-rational-or-irrational

Comment: Also Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value to which the sequence converges is called the [Nested radical constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html), no closed-form expression is known for this constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is perhaps an approach. Let 
$$
A_k = \sqrt{k + \sqrt{k+1 + \sqrt{\ldots}}}
$$
then assuming $(A_k)$ exists,
$$
A_{k+1} = A_k^2-k
$$
and $A_1$ will give you what you are seeking.