# How to prove this limit involving a nested radical sequence$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Define the sequence $\{a_n\}$as follows
\begin{align*}
a_n=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}
\end{align*}
Apparently we can prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$exists(see [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists),and) we denote it by $l$. Then prove that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt[n]{l-a_n}=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}\tag{*}
\end{align*}

$1^\circ$It's easy to see that$\{a_n\}$is strict increasing。In order to prove that$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$exists，we only need to show that 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1}-a_n)$converges. 
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n=&\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}}-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}\\
=&\frac{\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}-\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}}
\end{align*}
By evaluating the last term above,we get
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1}}\left(\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}-\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}\right)
\end{align*}
 Repeating the above steps，we get
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n<&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1}}\frac{\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}-\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}\\
<&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1}}}-\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
<&\cdots\cdots\\
<&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\cdots \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\triangleq b_n\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Notice that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\cdot\frac{2^n\sqrt{n!}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=0<1
\end{align*}
Thus$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$converges，and associate$(1)$with M-discriminance we can conclude that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1}-a_n)$converges.

$2^\circ$For $l-a_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty (a_{k+1}-a_k)$，associate with$(1)$we get
\begin{align*}
l-a_n<&\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2^k\sqrt{k!}}
<\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2^{k-n}}\\
=&\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n+k+1}}{2^k}
=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n+k+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2^k}\\
=&\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}+\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot\frac{k+1}{\sqrt{n+k+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{2\sqrt{n}+A}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}~(\text{$A>0$is a constant})
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt[n]{l-a_n}<\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{n}+A}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\right)^{\frac1n}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
By using Stirling's formular，we know that $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$when $n\to \infty$．Then it's easy to see $\sqrt{n!}\sim \sqrt[4]{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{\frac{n}2}$. So
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{n}+A}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\right)^{\frac1n}
=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\frac{(2\sqrt{n})^\frac1n(1+\frac{A}{2\sqrt{n}})^\frac1n}{2\sqrt[4n]{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}2}}=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Then we let $n\to \infty$and take  superior limit in  $(2)$，and get
\begin{align*}
\varlimsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt[n]{l-a_n}\leqslant \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{n}+A}{2^n\sqrt{n!}}\right)^{\frac1n}=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

This problem puzzles me is how to prove $\varliminf_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt[n]{l-a_n}\geqslant \frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}$. I have tried hard, but without any progress. Can anyone help me?