# On the convergence of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{2+...+\sqrt[n+1]{n}}}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to study the convergence of the following sequence, 
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{2+...+\sqrt[n+1]{n}}}$$

I don't know how to deal with it. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Do you need the explicit value of the limit or just the convergence?

Comment: @RobertZ Both can be, if you get the exact value better.

Comment: is the answer anyhow converging to $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend This obviously does not converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence 
$$a_n:=\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt[4]{3+\sqrt[5]{\dots+\sqrt[n+1]{n}}}}}$$
is increasing and bounded above by
$$b_n:=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{\dots+\sqrt{n}}}}}$$
which is convergent by [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Hence $a_n$ converges to a finite real number $L\in (1,2)$ (see achille hui's answer).