# How to proof that the limit of this square root is $3$?

Tags: calculus

$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{(n-1)\sqrt{n}}}}}}$$

I know how to deal with roots like that when there is addition (like this: [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists)), but I have no idea what to do with multiplying.

Comment: for $n\to \infty$? what is the source of this problem?

Comment: This expression is $2^{1/2}3^{1/4}4^{1/8}\cdots n^{1/2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: yes, $\ n -> \infty $

Comment: @Emily You mean `n\to\infty`.

Comment: Please read [Somos' quadratic recurrence constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos%27_quadratic_recurrence_constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wanted quantity is not three. It is
$$ \exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{2^n} $$
and the inner series can be easily approximated via summation by parts and creative telescoping:

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}S&=&\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log(n+1)}{2^n}\\&=&\lim_{N\to +\infty}\left[(1-2^{-N})\log(N+1)-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(1-2^{-n}\right)\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\right]\\&=&\log(2)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)=\log(2)+2\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)}{2^n}\end{eqnarray*} $$
approximately equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*}&& \log(2)+2\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{2^n}\left[\frac{1}{n+\tfrac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{12\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)}\right]\\&=&\log(2)-\frac{143}{30}+\frac{49}{6\sqrt{2}}\log(1+\sqrt{2})\end{eqnarray*}$$
which is a number slightly larger than $1$. It follows that
$$ C=\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\sqrt{5\sqrt{\ldots}}}}} $$
is slightly larger than $e$, but definitely less than $3$. By Frullani's theorem we also have the following integral representation for $C$:

$$ C = \exp \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2(1-e^{-x})}{x(2e^x-1)}\,dx\leq \exp\int_{0}^{+\infty} 2 e^{-5x/2}\left(1+\tfrac{25}{24}x^2\right)\,dx = \exp\left(\tfrac{16}{15}\right).  $$

Answer (score 0):

Actually products are easier because their logarithms are sums. In this case the result is $\exp\sum_{n\ge 2}2^{-n}\ln n$. The polylogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_s(z):=\sum_{n\ge 1}z^n n^{-s}$ satisfies $-\partial_s\operatorname{Li}_s(z):=\sum_{n\ge 2}z^n n^{-s}\ln n$, so your expression is $\exp-\partial_s\operatorname{Li}_s(z)|_{s=0,\,z=1/2}$.

Comment: Do you know how to do that without derivatives?