# sequence with nested radicals : finding an equivalent and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $x_n=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+....+\sqrt{n}}}}$ 
prove that $x_{n+1}^2 \leq 1+\sqrt{2}x_n$ and $x_n$ converges 
find an equivalent to $x_n$

Comment: actually , i am not able to find the equivalent

Comment: What is meant by "an equivalent?"

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists)

Answer (score 0):

To prove the inequality you just square $x_{n+1}$ like that:

$x_{n+1}^2=1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\dots \sqrt{n+1}}}$.

Now you use the simple fact, that

$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\dots}}=\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2\dots}}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{8+\dots}}$

and you derive at the inequality.

You should take a look at [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists)