# Determine if the following (unusual) 'series' converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that 'series' like these converge (and I apologize for formatting)
sqrt(1 + sqrt(1 + sqrt(1 + sqrt(1 + ...)))) (with 1 going on forever), for any constant they converge.
sqrt(n + sqrt(n + sqrt(n + sqrt(n + ...)))).  This can be solved by setting x = the value = sqrt(n + x) and solving for x.

But I am wondering about this series.
sqrt(1 + sqrt(2 + sqrt(3 + sqrt(4 + ...)))).

It has been a long time since I have looked at this  sort of thing, and I can upper bound it by  sqrt(1)+sqrt(sqrt(2))+sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(3))) + ...  which diverges, so does not  help, and I've thought about ratio tests and things like that, but that requires an actual series , which is hard to describe.  We could set something up like a limit sequence, a_1 = sqrt(1), a_2 =  sqrt(1+sqrt(2)), a_3=sqrt(1+sqrt(2+sqrt(3)), etc, and look at a_n as n approaches infinity.  But I'm out of ideas on what to do here.  Checking on a computer, it does appear to converge, but I'm wary of something like the harmonic series, which grows very slowly.  Can anyone give me any pointers on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this? [How can I show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt\ldots}}}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437209/42969)

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you Martin R for the math formatting examples.  I had used TeX a very long time ago, but did not see much formatting help in the Wiki Markup for the question itself.